Bootloop issue when installing the latest firmware on my new MKS Robin Nano V3.1
I've got a new Robin Nano V3.1 (with 5 TMC2209s and a TS35 screen) and I'm trying to update the firmware.
I powered up the board when I got it and everything seemed to be working fine (i.e. the interface was working) and then I tried to upload the latest version of the firmware using a 2GB (FAT) SD Card (newly formatted).
Firmware: https://github.com/makerbase-mks/MKS-Robin-Nano-V3.X
I copied the files from the bootloader/Beep folder onto the SD card and inserted it into the board and powered it on.


The board powers up and says it's updated. The file nano_v3_bootloader.bin is renamed to NANO_V3_BOOTLOADER.CUR.
But the board is now stuck in a boot loop. The screen flashes (slightly) twice each time it attempts to boot, and on the second flash it beeps.
Did I do something wrong? What do I need to do to put things right?

Everything worked exactly as expected when I used a 64mb thumb drive to update the firmware using the USB port.
